# iOS TestSuite example with XCTest

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, xctest, test-suite

Here is my test file

```
- (void)setUp{ [super setUp]; }

- (void)tearDown{ [super tearDown]; }

- (void)test0{ //.. }

- (void)test1{ //.. }
```

Now I want to add `test0` and `test1` to a `testSuite`, I notice that there is API for "`XCTest/XCTestSuite.h`" provided by `XCTest`, but I have no idea how to use it. Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What do you mean with test suite? Do you have a unit test target? Are these methods within a subclass os `XCTestCase`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you define test0 and test1 as methods in an XCTestCase subclass, they belong to a test suite named for the subclass.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks @Jon Reid